# Submit a form with Java (POST)

Tags: java, forms, http

I'm trying to submit a form to a certain website from Java (over HTTP), but when reading the response I don't see what I expected.
What exactly I do: first of all, I open the website in a browser, fill in the form by hand and submit it. In Chrome I can see the data that goes over the wire, i.e.:

```
Request URL:http://wizzair.com/en-GB/Select
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1061
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:WRUID=0; ASP.NET_SessionId=3e3ahach1d34oyhtoqfshxhe; Culture=en-GB; __utma=17431487.361991764.1292186668.1354138010.1354651562.81; __utmb=17431487.9.9.1354652614319; __utmc=17431487; __utmz=17431487.1319145359.34.18.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=wizz
Host:wizzair.com
Origin:http://wizzair.com
Referer:http://wizzair.com/en-GB/Select
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.91 Safari/537.11
Form Dataview URL encoded
__EVENTTARGET:HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView_AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView_ButtonSubmit
__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUBMGRkNSMYF94e4mXCiiJGEJbRixyidoa2QXSambTT2mm6cLs=
HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$OriginStation:EIN
HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$DestinationStation:OTP
HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$DepartureDate:02/02/2013
HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$ReturnDate:05/02/2013
HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$PaxCountADT:1
HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$PaxCountCHD:0
HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$PaxCountINFANT:0
HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$BaggageCount:0
HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$ButtonSubmit:Search
```

So I try to simulate the same request from a Java program, i.e.:

```
        public void doSubmit(String url, Map<String, String> data) throws Exception {
    URL siteUrl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "WRUID=0; ASP.NET_SessionId=3e3ahach1d34oyhtoqfshxhe; Culture=en-GB; __utma=17431487.361991764.1292186668.1354138010.1354651562.81; __utmb=17431487.9.9.1354652614319; __utmc=17431487; __utmz=17431487.1319145359.34.18.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=wizz");

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    Set keys = data.keySet();
    Iterator keyIter = keys.iterator();
    String content = "";
    for(int i=0; keyIter.hasNext(); i++) {
        Object key = keyIter.next();
        if(i!=0) {
            content += "&";
        }
        content += key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
    }
    System.out.println(content);
    out.writeBytes(content);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

.... which I call with the following parameters, as seen in the HTTP form data above:

```
    String url = "http://wizzair.com/en-GB/Select";
    Map<String, String> data = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    data.put("__EVENTTARGET", "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView_AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView_ButtonSubmit");
    data.put("__VIEWSTATE", "/wEPDwUBMGRkNSMYF94e4mXCiiJGEJbRixyidoa2QXSambTT2mm6cLs=\n"+
            "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$OriginStation:EIN\n"+
            "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$DestinationStation:OTP\n"+
            "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$DepartureDate:02/02/2013\n"+
            "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$ReturnDate:05/02/2013\n"+
            "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$PaxCountADT:1\n"+
            "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$PaxCountCHD:0\n"+
            "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$PaxCountINFANT:0\n"+
            "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$BaggageCount:0\n"+
            "HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$ButtonSubmit:Search"
```

However, the response I get back is simply a generic web page from that web site, not the answer I expected. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot,
Greetings,
    Sorin

Comment: what is the difference between what you expect and what you get?

Comment: And the [HTML](http://wizzair.com/en-GB/Search) doesn't seem a friendly one - maybe the content you are interested in is even constructed by client side javascript. You'd better use an API if you have control over the server - if you don't, well, I don't think it's a wise choice to build a program over it

Comment: You seem to be invoking an ASP.NET website. Those aren't very amenable to this sort of automation. I'd consider using something that drives a real browser and replicates the GUI actions needed to accomplish your result instead of trivial screenscraping. (Selenium, WATIR, PhantomJS, EnvJS, maybe some way of embedding a headless WebKit in Java.)

Comment: I suggest for you to start using some fancy HTTP protocol framework. I personally prefer Apache HTTP client and have no problems with posting forms. With proper configuration, you will be able to post message with literraly 6 lines of code. In my work I need to handle some ASP pages just like you are trying to do, and i must say, framework saved a lot of time for me. Try it yourself. I can provide some example code if you will need some.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you populate the post data is not correct. You should have ten or so key/value pairs, and not only two. The second item you see in Chrome is not one big string. Things like 'HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$OriginStation' is a key in its own right. This also applies to the other very very ugly named keys who all start with 'HeaderControlGroupRibbonSelectView$AvailabilitySearchInputRibbonSelectView$'.

Further, you need to encode the 'key' of the each post data item as well and not only the value of the key (because of the $-characters inside). Encode both sides with separate calls, to avoid encoding the assignment '='.

You also need to remove the newline at the end of your original second, but now split key/value, because it is just not there. This also applies to the third, fourth, etc. item.

Be carefull with interpreting what you see in Chrome :-P

Another thing: the website you are referring to is strongly session based: it keeps track of the current state of your interaction using the cookie value 'ASP.NET_SessionId'. This value is only short lifed. In general you should first make a call to this website without this cookie value, and the website will provide it for you (redirecting you to a country specific localized catch-all page). Subsequently you can use its value in your (second) request to harvest data. If you supply an invalid session id, you will be redirected to the same default page again, again and again.